# In tkinter button is not showing

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I don't know why but button is not showing - probably some simple mistake but I don't see it. Please help

I use python 3 if it helps

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button, Entry, IntVar, END, W, E, filedialog, BOTH, Frame, LEFT

class Resizer(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        master.title("Resizer")

        def askdir():
            self.dir_opt = options = {}
            options['initialdir'] = '~/'
            options['mustexist'] = False
            options['parent'] = root
            options['title'] = 'This is a title'
            filedialog.askdirectory(**self.dir_opt)

        Button(self, text='askopenfile', command=askdir).pack()

root = Tk()
my_gui = Resizer(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button isn't visible because it's parent (`my_gui`) isn't visible. You need to use `pack`, `place` or `grid` on `my_gui` to make it visible. For example:

```
my_gui = Resizer(root)
my_gui.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```